# Call function on pass input in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call the function in every input pass on textbox, but it does not work., either when i enter any input or remove input..it is work like intellisense textbox

```
<input id="btnSearch" type="text" value="Search" class="search_btn" onchange="Call()" />
    <script>
    function Call()
    {
    alert("Me");
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: What you want to do? Its not clear from your question or code! Why did you do a on change for a button!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably what you want to do is -

```
<input id="txt_Search" type="text" onchange="Call()" />
<script>
function Call()
{
     alert("Search suggestions can come here!!");
}

</script>
```

Or, using simple jQuery

```
$("#txt_Search").keyup( function() {
    var searchQuery = $("#txt_Search").val();
    alert("Seacrh suggestion satrting with - " + searchQuery);
});
```

Comment: yes its typo  on type

Comment: Try both the scripts, and see which works for you.

Comment: You can bind `onchange`, `onkeyup`, `onpaste` and `oninput` event with your input element

Answer (score -1):

you can also use textbox events -

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" onchange="SetDefault($(this).val());" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();">
```

jquery -

```
function SetDefault(Text){
  alert(Text);
}
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/fXnFF/291/)